# If you run out of time on Crumbling vault, do you die?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am on Hardcore mode.  If I try to farm the Crumbling Vault event, and do not make it in time...will my character die if I do not finish the event within the timer?

Or does it just end the event, and you have to get it to spawn again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was actually wondering this myself too just recently when I encountered this event. It turns out that no, your character doesn't automatically die if you run out of time; you just can't get the bonus loot at the end of the dungeon, and you don't get the achievement associated with the event.

Here's a video I found that illustrates that nothing special happens when the timer runs out:

Answer (score 1):

[A quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=diablo+3+crumbling) leads to [this wiki page](http://www.diablowiki.net/Crumbling_Vault) which states:

> If the player doesn't finish the event in time, a message will pop up informing that the hero has failed the quest. The player doesn't die, as was the original version of the event as seen in BlizzCon 2009.